# IF Ampscript - if a record from one data extension exists in another

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, if

Is there a way to write an IF ampscript to say:

If records from Data extension A, exist in Data extension B, then display 'Welcome Back' ELSE display 'welcome'?

Comment: Yes there is. You should use the [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/lookup.html) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to identify how a record in DE A is same as the one in DE B. Then you can use `LookupRows` function. I would combine it with `Iif` function.
Here is a sample in email:

```
%%[
    set @value = AttributeValue('column in DE A')
    set @DEname = 'Data Extension B'
    set @data = LookupRows(@DEname, 'column in DE B', @value)
    set @count = RowCount(@data)
]%%
%%=IIf(@count > 0, 'Welcome Back', 'welcome')=%%
```